# Update/Set ordering?

Tags: sql-server

I'm curious as to why the following `update` statement is not setting as expected:

```
DECLARE @int INT
SET @int = 0;

UPDATE #jc_TEMP
SET Num =  @int, @int = @int + 1
```

I would expect this to set the first row to 0 and THEN update. Do local variables get set first, before fields?

Comment: Are you trying to do a quirky update?

Comment: @Xedni I'm not sure what you mean by quirky update. I'm just updating an INT column to be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... just for kicks more or less.

Comment: Yeah, the variables get evaluated first. FWIW, there are probably better ways to do this. But if it's just for kicks, you could instead to `set num = @int - 1`

Comment: @Xedni Could you provide a better way? Just curious. Also, do you know of any documentation about the variable evaluation? THANKS!

Comment: Official documentation? No. But the "updating a column with a variable and then reassigning the variable" is known as a quirky update. On rare occasion I've used them for certain types of operations SQL is bad at. `http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/`. The reason this is a little sketchy is that it, conditionally, does it in the order of the primary key, but unless you take certain precautions, you may not be assured the numbers are applied to any given row. If that doesn't matter, Wonderful! If it does, I'd join the table to itself and update using row_number().

Comment: @Xedni You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The process of doing an update on a table with a variable that then gets assigned repeatedly in the same statement is sometimes referred to as a "quirky update". It's an undocumented feature of SQL Server which, if controlled correctly will quickly update rows in the order of the primary key. I've used it on a few occasions for things like running totals in pre-2012. There are quite a few gotchas, as with any undocumented procedure, but a good intro is this article from SSC

`http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/`

To answer the first question, yes. variables get evaluated first. I just know this from trial and error, so I can't point you to a specific article documenting that behavior.

Be warned as I mentioned above that unless you do this right, you can't be guaranteed of the order in which the updates will occur. If you're doing this in a production system, I'd recommend joining the table to itself and using the `row_number()` window function instead. Something like:

```
update a
set num = x.num
from #jc_temp a
inner join (select num = row_number() over (order by num)
            from #jc_temp) x
    on a.num = x.num
```